# Why is my archery skill lowered in the skills view?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 30 archery after I trained it a bit. I chose the Eagle Eye perk which required 30 archery. However, the skill is in bright red and only shows 20. I assume I have a debuff of some kind, but going to Magic->Active Effects shows nothing that would cause that.

Any ideas?

It's reverted back to 30+, but I still don't know what happened.

Comment: @Fabian I did say I had tried that :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an occasional bug that many people (myself included) have experienced.  For reasons currently unknown, a skill will be debuffed down to its starting level for your character's race.  Increasing your skill level (whether through normal skill usage, training, reading a skill book, etc.) generally seems to restore the skill to its proper value.

If you're on the PC version, you can also fix it by opening the console and issuing the command `player.modav skillname 1` followed by `player.modav skillname -1`.  Note that the internal name of the Archery skill is "Marksman", not "Archery".

Comment: Dave sherohman@ player.modav skillname 1 followed by player.modav skillname -1 ( do i copy this into the consol, or do i change anything

Comment: @Metalsurface: Change "skillname" to the name of the skill you're fixing, but, other than that, just type it into the console, yes. For the internal names of the skills, Archery is called "marksman" and Speech is called "speechcraft".  All others are the same as the name in the skill interface, but with any spaces and hyphens removed (e.g., "onehanded" instead of "one-handed").

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the appropriate NPC to purchase a skill increase for that particular skill and that should resolve the issue.  You can probably try upping the skill through different means as well, but this way, you don't have to risk fighting enemies at the potentially lower skill level :)