# Skyrim skill damage cure?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my archery skill lowered in the skills view?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/why-is-my-archery-skill-lowered-in-the-skills-view)

My archery skill is over 40 but on the skills screen shows up in red at 25. It seems to be damaged somehow but i have no negative effects on my character. Has anyone else noticed a skill debuff like this? If so can it be removed?

Comment: Previous games had you pray at a shrine to remove skill damage.

Comment: There's nothing listed under active effects?

Comment: This is a bug. I can confirm that curing poison, curing disease, resting, load/restart, shrine or unequipping everything doesn't fix this. It also isn't listed in the active effects. I have heard the bug affecting markmanship (red 15 or 25) and seen it affect one-handed (red 15). Leveling (propably training) or console commands (see Chris' answer) fix this.

Comment: Here answer is a bit easier to read and use: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35348/why-is-my-archery-skill-lowered-in-the-skills-view

Answer (score 7):

**For PC Users Only**

If this bug occurs :

1. Press the key for the dev console (this is usually a `~` with a `` ` right below it on the key)
2. Type exactly as written (in place of `x` type the bugged skill, and in place of `y` type the amount of the skill you need to restore to get your original skill level)

   ```
   player.modAV x y
   ENTER
   ```
3. Your skill should now be `y` points ahead of what it was before the bug (it should also be green)
4. Again, type exactly as written (the `-` next to the `y` implies exactly that, type `-` next to what your `y` value was)

   ```
   player.modAV x -y
   ENTER
   ```

Your skill should now be restored to its original value.

****The skill names used in place of x are not necessarily what you see in the skill menu. Check this page for the in game names http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices. Also if you can't remember what your skill should be at use the console code tgm to turn on god mode and run around using the skill until it levels up.

Comment: tried player.modAV ARCHERY 10 I got an error on the console. didn't work unless i am misunderstanding what is meant by "bugged skill"

Comment: @chris It is "player.setav marksman y", not archery.

Comment: I just got this problem, and this answer fixed it. +1!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Un-equip everything, make sure all diseases are cured, heal using the healing spell, and sleep in a bed. I did all that and it worked. Also, try praying at the alter behind the yelling guy in Whiterun.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using the commands, just go to the appropriate NPC to purchase a skill increase for that particular skill and that should resolve the issue.  You can probably try upping the skill through different means as well, but this way, you don't have to risk fighting enemies at the potentially lower skill level :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use the damaged skill until you level up. This sets it back to where it should be.