# Skills randomly changing/resetting

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Recently, my skills in Skyrim have been going up and down. Some skills have reset to 15 and others have jumped up to 100 that weren't at 100 before. I made my Pickpocketing skill legendary pretty recently, but that shouldn't cause other skills to change, right?

Restoration was originally at around 50 and it jumped up to 100, but then went down to 90.

Leveling the skills normally doesn't get them back to normal and neither do skill books.

Edit: I'm playing on PC and the only mods I have installed are graphical mods

Comment: This is strange behavior. I'm guessing you are playing on the PC version of Skyrim? Are you running any mods? If so, a list of them might be helpful.

Comment: The known bug that is similar to the problem you describe is usually fixed by leveling up the skill normally. Since you note that this doesn't work, you can try using the console if you're on the PC version, by entering the commands listed in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40908/18669) in a related question. As @twobugs noted, mods could be the culprit. You can also try disabling them and testing whether your skills act normally then.

Comment: Are you using any mods that modify skills? It's always a good idea to include what mods you use (even if that's "no mods") and which platform you play on.

Comment: (1) Are you certain that your mods are only and purely graphical?
(2) Have you changed your mods?
(3) Have you used the showracemenu command, or other console commands?

Comment: Maybe your wife is messing with your head. Mine did that to me once by creating an exact replica of my character and replacing some of my saves with hers.